# HANA SQL result set presentation

Tags: sql, eclipse, hana, presentation

Whenever I run e.g. a SQL SELECT statement from the SQL Console in Eclipse, I get tabs. One with the script and one with the result.

I prefer SSMS' version, where the result set is being presented in a **window **instead of a tab, such that I can look at the result set while coding. Is this possible to setup?

I tried modifying the Window tab, have been running thru the preferences to see if I could find the functionality.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJrK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Editor Eclipse plug-in that comes with HANA Studio does not allow for changing the output tab to a window (or to anything different, really).

For working with SQL/SQLScript I personally prefer [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) which has wide adoption across the HANA user base (see e.g. [here](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-jdbc.html), [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/01/08/good-things-come-together-dbeaver-sap-hana-spatial-beer/), [here](https://www.lbreddemann.org/getting-data-into-hana-the-easy-way/) ...)

DBeaver allows for a wide range of output configurations and especially keeping the code editable and the result set visible in the same window.